# Python: Factory attributes

Tags: python, factory

Is `setup.inQ` different from `complete.inQ`?

If I put something in one queue, it wouldn't show up in the other queue, correct?

```
import Queue


class Factory:
    name = ""
    inQ = Queue.Queue()
    outQ = Queue.Queue()

    def worker(self): pass

    @staticmethod
    def getFactory(factory_name):
        if factory_name == "setup":
            return SetupFactory()
        elif factory_name == "dispatch":
            return DispatchFactory()
        elif factory_name == "complete":
            return CompleteFactory()
        else:
            return None

class SetupFactory(Factory):
    name = "setup"

    def worker(self):
        #extend

class DispatchFactory(Factory):
    name = "dispatch"
    def worker(self):
        #extend

class CompleteFactory(Factory):
    name = "complete"
    def worker(self):
        #extend

setup = Factory.getFactory("setup")
complete = Factory.getFactory("complete")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy enough to test:

```
>>> import Queue
>>> class A(object):
...   q = Queue.Queue()
... 
>>> class B(A):
...   pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> b.q is a.q
True
```

We see that the `q` attribute is indeed shared across subclasses.  (putting things in `b.q` is the exact same things as putting things in `a.q`).

This makes sense because `A.q` is an attribute of the class, so it gets created when `A` gets created.  Python doesn't create a new one when `B` gets created since `B` just inherits properties and methods from `A`.

Generally speaking, if you want to have a property that isn't shared across instances of a class, you'd put it in the class's initialization function (`__init__`) which gets called magically by python when you create an instance of a class:

```
class Factory(object):
    name = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.inQ = Queue.Queue()
        self.outQ = Queue.Queue()
```

Comment: ah ok thank you. so i would have to move the Queue.Queue() to each of the  classes if i dont an item to show up in all queues

Comment: @ealeon -- I think you probably want to move that code to `__init__`

Comment: ohhh yeah ill try that!